# CSS select last two child element if it has even number of child else last one element if it has odd number of element

Tags: css

I have html as follows 
Case Odd number of child element i.e "item"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
</div>
```

I have to write a css selector such that, css applies only in **c**.
Case Even number of child element i.e "item"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
</div>
```

I have to write a css selector such that, css applies only in **c** and **d**.

Comment: if i have even number of child element, it may be 2 4 6 8.. then css should be applied for last two element only
if i have even number of child element, it may be 1 3 5 9... then css should be applied for last one element only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that you always need to select the `:last-child` and the before `:last-child` only if its and odd element:

```css
.item:last-child,
.item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd){
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For example like this:

```css
.container .item:last-child,
.container .item:nth-last-of-type(-n+2):not(:nth-child(even)) {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
</div>
```